# Where is the code of gRPC that handles deadline in the client stub?

Tags: grpc

I'm searching for when deadline starts to count down and how deadline is handled in detail in the client stub in gRPC. I think that src/cpp/client/generic_stub.cc may tell some details. In the following code block from generic_stub.cc, I think CallInternal() may include such details, but I don't find via software called Understand what CallInternal() actually does.

```
// begin a call to a named method
std::unique_ptr<grpc::GenericClientAsyncReaderWriter> GenericStub::Call(
    grpc::ClientContext* context, const grpc::string& method,
    grpc::CompletionQueue* cq, void* tag) {
  return CallInternal(channel_.get(), context, method, cq, true, tag);
}
```

So, which part of the code in gRPC contains the detail I desire? Very looking forward to an answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In grpc, deadlines aren't being "counted down", they are always absolute values that are checked against the current time.

The piece of code inside grpc that does any deadline check is located here:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.21.3/src/core/ext/filters/deadline/deadline_filter.cc

In terms of code organization, the C++ upper layer you're looking at isn't doing a lot of logic, so you won't find informations like these here. The grpc core that is shared among the various wrapped languages is the place to look, usually.

Comment: I read `deadline_filter.cc`. All functions are called from `client_channel.cc` at the very beginning. Besides, In butterfly graph of `start_timer_if_needed()`, `Start()`, `Stop()` and `Cancel()`. Although I think these are timer start, stop and cancel respectively, They are functions of class `CallCombiner`, not `Timer` for instance.

So does the call combiner means that deadline is usually maintained for a batch of invokes, not for a single calls?

Comment: The call combiner is irrelevant to your question, as we do apply deadlines on a per-call basis, and is in fact triggered from `client_channel.cc`

Comment: I read the function `void CallData::StartTransportStreamOpBatch(grpc_call_element* elem, grpc_transport_stream_op_batch* batch)` in `client_channel.cc`, where `calld->PendingBatchesAdd(elem, batch)` is invoked before `CallData::StartPickLocked(void* arg, grpc_error* error)`. `PendingBatchesAdd` add batch in the pending list and `StartPickLocked` starts the timer, which means the timer is started after batch is added to pending list. So the question is, can I see this pending list as sending queue of client in RPC?